# How to bubble events from a class of controls to the parent form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a form with ~40 different textboxes on it.  Recently they've asked me to add functionality so they can run a report when they press enter (instead of clicking a button).
So, I'm trying to create a generic event handler on my form to catch an event raised in the various controls (instead of attaching the handler to ever control that I create).
I've got the code running, but the event doesn't seem to bubble up to the main form.  Could you point out where I'm missing something?

```
Public Class TextboxSelect
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler Enter, AddressOf selectText
        AddHandler KeyDown, AddressOf raiseEnterEvent
    End Sub

    Public Event enterPressed As EventHandler
    Private Sub selectText(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim text As TextboxSelect = CType(sender, TextboxSelect)
        text.SelectionStart = 0
        text.SelectionLength = text.Text.Length + 1
    End Sub

    Public Sub raiseEnterEvent(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent enterPressed(Me, New EventArgs)
        If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then
            RaiseEvent enterPressed(Me, New EventArgs)
        End If
    End Sub End Class
```

Main Form:

```
Private Sub textboxEnterSearch(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles this.enterPressed
    MessageBox.Show("You hit enter in a textbox!")
End Sub
```

When debugging, I was raising the enterPressed event, but it seems that that event isn't bubbled up to the form.

Comment: If you set a button as `AcceptButton` of your `Form`, then when you press `Enter` on any of your `TextBox` controls, the code of that button will be run.  Using this feature it seems you don't need to write any code for handling Enter key, do you?

Comment: What is `this`? You must add the event handler to all text boxes.

Comment: @RezaAghaei theoretically, I wouldn't need the code in the textboxSelect class if I did that, but wouldn't it also cause it to run if the user pressed the enter key when they weren't in a textbox?

Comment: @VisualVincent good point... this is vb.net

Comment: You can do anything in `AcceptButton` event handler, for example you can check `ActiveControl` of your `Form` or anything else. Also instead of creating a new event type and a new control type, you can simply override `ProcessCmdKey` or `ProcessDialogKey` method of the `Form`.

Comment: `Public Event EnterPressed(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`  why do you RaiseEvent twice in the KeyDown event?

Comment: @Plutonix it was for debugging to see if the event was actually being raised.  I probably should have removed it, or just removed the code specifying the enter key when I posted it.

Comment: BTW this sounds like one of those...."OH WAIT.. We changed our minds. We really don't want it to do that after all...".. requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a handler in the load section of the form:

```
Dim cv = GetAllControls(Me).OfType(Of TextboxSelect)
        For Each obj In cv
            Dim bob As TextboxSelect = CType(obj, TextboxSelect)
            AddHandler bob.KeyDown, AddressOf enterBox
        Next
```

Here's the function referenced in the code:

```
Private Function GetAllControls(container As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Dim controlList As New List(Of Control)()
    For Each c As Control In container.Controls
        controlList.AddRange(GetAllControls(c))
        If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
            controlList.Add(c)
        End If
    Next
    Return controlList
End Function
```

Then in the handler I called different functions based on the naming convention (which, thankfully, was consistent).

Code for choosing differentiating different controls:

```
    Private Sub enterBox(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)

    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If CType(sender, TextboxSelect).Name Like "*Cmd1*" Then
            Cmd1_Click(sender, e)
        Else
            Cmd2Search_Click(sender, e)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a custom event on your control, nor attach a handler on every one of the controls your form has.

In the designer, set the `KeyPreview` property of your form to `True`. Then handle the `form_KeyDown` event, and check there if the `Enter` key was pressed.. The `KeyPreview` property of your form triggers the key events first on the form, and then on any control it was actually pressed.

Comment: So, how would I differentiate between an event raised by the form and one raised by the textbox?  I don't want this to trigger if the event isn't coming from a textbox.

Comment: If your textboxes are directly over your form, you can check the "Me.ActiveControl" property to get which control has focus

Answer (score 1):

To check who raised the event -

```
 If TypeOf ActiveControl Is TextBox Then
   ....
```